# executing /bin/ls in a C program and cannot access directories with ~ in path

Tags: c, linux

I want to implement some pipes and reproduce a ls |sort |grep command
so i started with the ls part and for testreasons i wanted to print out the conclusion from bin/ls part but i cant access upper directories

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-lR", directy, NULL);
```

I want to access for example ~/Desktop which works fine from the shell but not from the program itself.
I tried out multiple different versions and can access a subdirectory of hte current folder

Comment: what string does directy point to?

Comment: Can it be that ~ is not interpreted as the home directory?

Comment: directy is my input in the Desktop example it would be ~/Desktop i also had the idea that something ist wrong with the way i input the directory but the exact same works fine in the shell and i couldnt find anything at all how i should write it differently

Comment: Expansion of `~` is a feature of the shell program. The shell replaces it with the contents of the `HOME` environment variable if set, or with the home directory of the user executing the shell. The shell also expands `~loginname` to be the home directory of the given login name.

Comment: There is a library function `wordexp()` that can be used to perform shell-style word expansions.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Ian Abbott, expansion of ~ is a feature of the shell program. Instead you can use the *getenv* function and read the HOME environment variable so you can construct the string $HOME/Desktop.